# How to do groupby on the basis of indexand sum in python

Tags: python, pandas

My Data is

```
   Count
1   5
2   10
3    15
4    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
9    0
10   0
11    0
12   0
13   0
14   0
15   20
```

**Output:**

```
Group  Sum
0-10    30
11-20   20
```

Group by on the index no 10 in one group.

Comment: Please seperate code and text. Also elaborate question with proper output.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to group on a function of the index. Just do it:

```
resul = df.groupby((df.index-1)//10).sum()

# adjust the index from 0,1,... to 1-10,11-20,...
resul.index = [f'{10 * i + 1}-{10 * (i+1)}' for i in resul.index]
```

It gives:

```
       Count
1-10      30
11-20     20
```